# Allowing multi-select on a ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I know this question has been asked many times before, but having followed their suggestions; I have found that none of them lead to the desired effect.

What I want is to enable the user to select multiple items from a listView, and for each of these items to be shaded grey. At the moment, as soon as you select another item; the grey colour on the previously selected item is replaced with white; and the newly selected item is now grey.

This is my listView:

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="188dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >

</ListView>
```

This is how I populate the listView:

```
String[] teams = {"Blackburn","Manchester City", "Manchester United"};
ArrayAdapter<String>teamsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.teams, teams);
lstOne = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
lstOne.setAdapter(teamsAdapter);
```

Comment: Use a `StateListDrawable`, not a single color, for your `listSelector`. Use the framework's own `StateListDrawable` as a reference for what states you need.

Comment: Ah ok, how would this look though. Is this a property I need to add to the listView in xml?